# Symfony/Guzzle Basic Authorization not working

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle6

I have installed the Guzzle Bundle in my application and am getting a 401 unauthorized response when I call it.  In my Dev RestClient there is a setting for Basic Auth I put in the username and password and it works. However I can't get it to work in my controller using symfony. My guess is that there is something in the config.yml that I'm not understanding.

**The Controller**

```
/**
 * Charting\Backoffice controller.
 */
class BackOfficeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all MTI_Cart\AODHomePage entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="backoffice_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $client = $this->get('guzzle.client.api_backoffice');
        $response = $client->get('/users');
        var_dump($response); die;    
    }
}
```

**And my config**

```
guzzle:
clients:
    api_backoffice:
        base_url: "http://chartingapi.com"

        # custom headers
        headers:
            Accept: "application/json"

        # guzzle client options (full description here: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html)
        # NOTE: "headers" option is not accepted here as it is provided as described above.
        options:
            auth:
                - backoffice                # login
                - mysupercoolpassword       # password
            timeout: 30

        # plugin settings
        #plugin:
            #wsse:
                #username: backoffice
                #password: mysupercoolpassword

    #####in case we want to consume another api
    #api_some_otherapi:
    #    base_url: "http://api.crm.tld"
    #   headers:
    #        Accept: "application/json"
```

P.S... The spacing above is correct, just haven't figured out how to make this input form to behave like I want it to. (just imagine guzzle over to the left 4 spaces)

So to reitirate: when I run the username and password as listed in the config above It works fine in POSTMAN, but i get 401 unauthorized when running it with this config/guzzle

Comment: `clients` or `client`, which one?

Comment: I have tried both... the documentation is for clients in the config file and for client in the container call...  When I use clients in the container call to match the config file the error I get is "You have requested a non-existant service".  I have documented the 'mismatch' here, because that is the way it is in the documentation. [link](https://github.com/8p/GuzzleBundle)

Comment: What is actually being sent as the request?

Comment: I gave up on this bundle and decided to write my own  service for Curl... Thanks for your help though